# Non Angular : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'CryptoJS' of undefined

Tags: typescript, encryption, cryptojs, lit-element

I'm trying to use crypto-js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) for obvious reasons.
Mine is Non-Angular, LitElement, Typescript, Web Component application.
While running in local getting following error "**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'CryptoJS' of undefined**".

Code for the same

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
export class TestClass {
public encrypt() {
  console.log(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('key', 'somevalue').toString());
 }
}
```

If i debug index.js file /nodemodules/crypto-js/index.js
root is coming as undefined

```
; (function (root, factory, undef) {
// Some code
    // Global (browser)
root.CryptoJS = factory(root.CryptoJS); // getting root as undefined
```

Not sure, what whats the missing part. The same code works fine in Angular project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone struggling with importing crypto-js in typescript(as its in UMD format), can use crypto-es package. Its available in ES format.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-es

Answer (score 0):

Use it in deno: `import CryptoJS from '../../node_modules/crypto-es/lib/index.js'`

deno run CryptoTest.ts

```
let words = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==");
let base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(words);
console.log(words.words, base64);
```